# can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any docker compose (docker-compose section not getting added in solution)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.0

I've installed docker on my windows (10), and when I try to build a new project, I always get the following error:

```
Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
    parent. Are you in the right directory?

    Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

When i check the project i created in visual studio 2017, i don't see **docker-compose** section in solution. It just has one project (.Net core 2.0) and one Dockerfile file in it.

Following are the steps i followed.

File-> new Project -> Asp.Net core web application -> API (Enable Docker Support) -> OK

[image]

and this is how my project structure looks like (no docker-compose section in it)

[image]

Am i missing anything here ?

Comment: This question seems to be more about visual studio 2017 then about docker,

Comment: even am suspecting that. But am not sure on what am i missing (either in VS or in Docker). So looking for some help here

Comment: the log message clearly said the you dont have `docker-compose` file, have you tried to add `docker-compose.yml` inside of your project directory. .?

Comment: do i have to create it manually for every solution that u create ? As i selected *Docker Support* while creating project, it is supposed to add that file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really an expert on VS 2017, but you would need to create a `docker-compose.yml` file inside of the project.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  client:
    container_name: WebApplication 
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
        # Any volumes you would mount goes here
    ports:
        # Ports that need to be mapped from container to host goes here
    environment:
        # Any environment variables
```

**Edit:** In order for VS 2017 to automatically create `docker-compose.yml`, you will need to right-click on the Project and select Add > Orchestrator Support (15.8 and greater) or Add > Docker Project Support (below 15.8).

Comment: do i have to create it manually for every solution that u create ? As i selected Docker Support while creating project, it is supposed to add that file

Comment: It looks like you can right-click your application and choose Add > Docker Project Support to generate the files for you.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Thanks for the reply. I even tried that but it just re-created Dockerfile but did not add docker-compose (yaml/yml) file

Comment: What version of VS 2017 do you have? For 15.8 or greater, you would need to do Add > Container Orchestrator Suppport

Comment: OMG..  You are life savior..... my VS version is 15.8.3. and selecting the Container Orchestrator Support worked for me.. It created docker-compose section with yml files...... Thank u very much Anthony... Please update your answer so that i will mark it as correct answer.. Cheers !!! :) :)

Comment: Edited answer :)

Comment: Thank you. Accepted your answer. :)